# Create filter to forward mail with modified title or content?

Tags: gmail

I know how to create a filter to forward mails in Gmail, but I need to modify the title or content of the filtered mail (e.g., append the sender's email address) and then forward it. Is there any way I can do it?

I need this feature because I have a place (program) to deal with these forwarded mails, and the **original sender's email address** is important to me. With current Gmail filter+forward I have no way to know the original sender's mail address when dealing with these mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not (currently) possible with Gmail filters.

The available actions on a Gmail filter are:

- Skip the Inbox (Archive it)
- Mark as read
- "Star" it
- Apply a label
- Forward it to a forwarding address
- Delete it
- Never send it to Spam
- Send a canned response
- Always/Never mark it as important
- Exclude from *SmartLabel* categorization

There's nothing there that will actually allow for changing any of the content. You would need to use some third-party tool (if one exists).